# Ударения в "полиграфия" и "география"

Tags: орфоэпия

ПолиграфИя и геогрАфия. Словарь говорит, что это связано с смысловым значением: промышленность и наука (как этногрАфия и телеграфИя). Но откуда происходит разное ударение в сложных словах одинакового происхождения?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Что за словарь - и почему вы говорите об одинаковом происхождении слов?

Answer (score 1):

> Словарь говорит, что это связано с смысловым значением

Не верьте этому! Никакой связи ударения со смысловым значением  у слова ***полиграфия*** нет!

Когда-то раньше правильным считалось ударение на третьем слоге: ***полигрАфия.***

У Ушакова нормативными считались и ***полигрАфия*** и ***полиграфИя***.

У Аванесова -- ***полиграфИя*** и *доп. устар.* ***полигрАфия***.

и т. д.

Сейчас опять возвращаемся к ***полигрАфии***.

И хоть в некоторых словарях пока ещё и отмечен в качестве единственно допустимого вариант ***полиграфИя***, *«Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты»* (М., 2012) считает более предпочтительным в наст. время совсем другой вариант. В нём так:

***полигрАфия*** и *допуст.* ***полиграфИя***.

Comment: Слава, Вы не поняли. Значения разные у "полиграфии" (и телеграфии) и "географии" (и этнографии). И не просто значения, а обобщенные, т.е. область деятельности. Наука и промышленность. Это понятно, вопрос в том, насколько верно как объяснение разных ударений.

Comment: Хореографию к нанотехнологиям отнести придётся, туда же —— сценографию, стенографию, шелкографию, фотографию...

Comment: А смысл вашего "придется"? Посоревнуйтесь еще, у кого тире длиннее.

Answer (score 0):

Катя, я не хотел отвечать на не совсем понятный мне вопрос, но коли slava1947 ответил, я попробую воспользоваться его пониманием, тем более, что есть что возразить.

Словарям надо верить. Ровно насколько, насколько они компетентны.

Здесь, видимо, за деревьями леса не увидели. Все, что связано с "графией" как описанием чего-либо имеет ударение на "гр**а**ф". Может и есть исключения, не я что-то не найду вот так сразу.

В остальных случаях возможны колебания, хотя тоже довольно редкие. Ваши телеграфия и полиграфия - едва ли не единственные варианты с таким ударением (нге считая производных и сходных по значению). 
В полиграфии стоит признать равноправными два варианта ударения. Собственно, это и дают словари, если слова в статье соединены союзом "и" то они обычно равноправны, если нет дополнительных помет. Я так понимаю и Ушакова, и Авнесова.

*Это не ответ "почему", это ответ "как".* 
А вот "почему" оно так - это уже вопрос философский. Язык у нас такой. Не все можно объяснить. Возможно потому, что в "описательных" (сиречь - научных) названиях основа "граф" еще хорошо ощущается. А вот в "телеграфии" она окончательно стерлась - подобные слова заимствовались независимо от "графических".